# Legend is not correct after saving to pdf (ggplot2 1.01 )

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I save the plot created from ggplot2 to a pdf by either using RStudio export option or `ggsave` command, the legend is messed up. Following compares the legend as created in RStudio (top) and the resulting pdf (bottom). How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? For example if I plot `ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, lty=Species)) + geom_line()` and Export in RStudio to PDF, the legend markers appear correctly.

Comment: What are you viewing the PDF in? It might help to `embedFonts()` on the PDF.

Comment: Adobe reader displays the messed up legend

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Unfortunately I can't share the data. For other datasets as in your example, the prob. doesn't occur.

Comment: Substitute random data with the same structure.